# React native issue : inserting an empty row

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, hook, crud

Testing some things in React and having some issues with some of my logic. I am trying to get value from inputs in a form then on submitting that form I want to take that object of input values and add them to my plant state. When I console log I get the state values but then the plant state is empty. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

```
      const [plant, setPlant] = useState();
          const [TypeofPlant, setType] = useState('')
          const [Phase, setPhase] = useState('')
          const [Days, setDay] = useState(null)
          const [Start, setStart] = useState(0)
          const [End, setEnd] = useState(0)
        
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {

        e.preventDefault()

          setPlant({...plant, 
            TypeofPlant: TypeofPlant,
            Phase: Phase,
            Days: Days,
            Start: Start,
            End: End,
        
       
        
        })
       
                DataService.addNewPlant(plant).then(() => {
      
                    })
                   },
                    (error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                    }
                );
```

DataService:

```
  addNewPlant(data){
        return http.post('/plants/add',data)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to console plant outside of DataService block.

Comment: thats return [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

The [Response.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) method interface takes a Response stream and reads it to completion. It returns a promise which resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON.

Update the code like below

```
....
DataService.addNewPlant(data).then(res => {
            const response = res.json();
            setPlant({
                TypeofPlant: response.data.TypeofPlant,
                Phase: response.data.Phase,
                Days: response.data.Days,
                Start: response.data.Start,
                End: response.data.End,
            })
            console.log(response.data);}
....
```

Comment: I tried this but it returns : [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: res.json is not a function. (In 'res.json()', 'res.json' is undefined)]

Comment: Try with updated code and let me know

Comment: I update my code res.data.json is not a function. (In 'res.data.json()', 'res.data.json' is undefined)]  I faced the same issue plant still empty

Comment: @KeltoumaIndtaher you can set data directly if it is the same data you want after executing addNewPlant => setPlant(data)

Comment: yeah but the problem is adding an empty row